# Creating Ribbon Styled Applications

Tags: delphi, ribbon

Using the standard Delphi TRibbon components I noticed they are not that brilliant.

- Firstly they dont look as nice as the Microsoft ones, for example the glow effects and colors in the TRibbon dont look as impressive as the ones used in Wordpad or Paint in Windows 7.
- Secondly if you want to create Ribbon Styled interfaces, I noticed that there is no Ribbon style menus or popup menus independent of the TRibbon. For the actual Ribbon there is, but if say for continuity purposes you wanted the Ribbon style popup menus assigned to a TListbox or TListView for example, there doesnt appear to be one.
- Thirdly, sometimes when a Ribbon Action is disabled, it still shows the Hot glow effect as if hovering over the Action, even though it is disabled.
- Finally I find it very fiddly trying to place container components such as a TCombobox in a group. It is really awkward sizing the controls and position etc.

I guess my point is that using the standard Delphi TRibbon components appears to be not the best approach both visually and useably. How can I make a Ribbon styled Application look and work as neatly as the Microsoft ones do just like I said before the way that Wordpad and Paint do in Windows 7?

Have a look at this comparison screenshot to get a better idea:

[image]

The Delphi Ribbon seems incomplete, unless I am expecting too much. I believed the Ribbon Components are to provide your Application with a better experience for the end user both visually and better workspace etc.

What suggestions could you give to enhance or make the TRibbon work and look like the Microsoft ones?

I dont use Ribbon Style Interfaces all the time so purchasing 3rd Party Components is not something I really want to do. I have looked at the TMS and DevExpress ones but for the price of them, they dont look as good either. The TMS ones look worse than the standard Delphi TRibbon.

Comment: Have you considered the COM versions supplied by MS? I think they'd be pretty hard work to use but I'm sure the end result would be of high quality.

Comment: As far as i know, the Delphi ribbon components are a "light" version of the DevExpress "ExpressBars".

Comment: You could try TMS Components ( http://www.tmssoftware.com ). They have their own native Delphi Ribbon component and their components are very attractive visually. Also, you can have the App butoon effect (app button rising above the caption) provided you descend your main form from a specific one they provide. Look at the demo's for more info.

Comment: @Andreas: **no**, they are not a light version of DevExpress controls. DevExpress ExpressBars have a totally different code and component interface.

Comment: @Andreas: I will confirm that our ribbon in ExpressBars has not been licensed to Embarcadero. No way are the Delphi ribbon components a "light" version of DevExpress' ribbon.

Comment: @Craig: In what way does the DevExpress ribbon not "look as good" as the Microsoft ribbon? Which style? In your example, you are comparing two different ribbon styles.

Comment: @boyetboy looking on the DevExpress website they looked different - not as clean and smooth as the Microsoft ones, but unless I tried them I wont know for sure. But like I said I dont use Ribbon Style interfaces enough anyway to  warrant purchasing 3rd party, when possible I try to make do with the standard issue Delphi components - although often limited to what they can do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a native look and feel, check the [Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi](http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml).

This is an Open Source wrapper around [the Windows Ribbon Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee658251.aspx) available since Windows 7 (and Vista after some official update is installed). This is the API used by the Windows 7 Word Pad.

Note also that you have two kind of layout: Office 2007 and Office 2010. The Delphi VCL Ribbon implements Office 2007 style, whereas the Windows Seven WordPad uses an Office 2010 style.

In some of our projects for some clients, we used [TMS software Ribbon components](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtoolbar.asp). The code is a bit over-sized (a lot of duplicates or bad written stuff like component persistence) but it works and renders well, supporting both 2007 and 2010 Ribbon styles. For our Clients, rendering was what mattered. For our Open Source framework, [we published a dual solution for building a Ribbon-like GUI](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=280), generated from code: it will use either standard VCL components for a basic layout, either the TMS components for a full Office 2007/2010 rendering. We just defined some classes, implemented by either libraries. If you use the generic components as defined in [SQLite3ToolBar](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/SQLite3ToolBar.pas) (i.e. the `TSynForm, TSynToolBar, TSynToolButton, TSynPopupMenu, TSynPage, TSynPager, TSynBodyPager` and `TSynBodyPage` classes) and [SynTaskDialog](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynTaskDialog.pas) (for `TSynButton`) in your own code, the USETMSPACK conditional will do all the magic for you.

We didn't use yet the Ribbon component as was introduced in Delphi 2009. Its action-driven design won't make it easy to interface with the event-driven design of our User Interface handling, and we have to confess that this component has rather bad reputation (at least in the Delphi 2009 version).

The great Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi won't fit our need of a on-the-fly generated Ribbon from code. Its design, from the Microsoft implementation itself, is to create the UI from an XML resource, linked at compilation... so it won't fit our needs, but it probably fit yours, for a more "static" application UI design.

If you use a Office-like Ribbon in your application, be aware of the [Office UI Licensing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809).

Comment: "The source code uses some features that were introduced in Delphi 2010, such as the new RTTI engine. So you will need Delphi 2010 or later to work with this library."  Damn.

Comment: @A.Bouchez i was just perusing the code to see how much i can salvage - a lot of constructs have been added to Object Pascal since the version of Delphi that i use.

Comment: @Ian Wasn't Clinton president when your version of Delphi was released?!

Comment: looks interesting I will most definitely look at this answer more closer.

Comment: I never heard about this before. Thanks for the scoop. My problem, I guess, is that I still have lots of Windows XP users, so unless I abandon them, or until they are gone, I won't be able to go to the Windows Ribbon Framework.

Comment: I have been following the tutorial for this and although it is never going to be as quick as simple putting a ribbon together compared to the Delphi IDE it does make much smoother professional looking User Interfaces.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Ooo, yes he was, just barely. Ahh the good ol' days.

Comment: AFAIK Office UI licensing has been retired. Please see the page in the link of my answer - Microsoft updated its content.

Answer (score 7):

The pragmatic answer is to use another component set. The [TMS Software version appears good](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtoolbar.asp) but I use the [DevExpress ExpressBars](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExBars/) one which works very well for me.

Comment: +1 for the DevExpress expressBars. If you can't do it with DevEx, , it probably can't be done.  If you want ribbons, go with DevEx.

Comment: maybe, but as I said I would rather not have to purchase a 3rd party component suite. The TMS Ribbon also looks worse than the standard TRibbon.

Comment: @Craig: if your time isn't worth money, then  you could always try modifying the VCL ribbon to look how you want it to look.  I don't believe there are any open source ribbons, and the wrappers using the MS stuff means you're depending on the MS .net controls which is not a smart long term move.  You'll rue the day you build such a dependency into your system.

Comment: @Warren This is not a "MS .net control", not part of the DotNet runtime, but part of the OS. From my little experiment, relying on OS/API controls is a very good approach: you'd be sure that the rendering on screen will match the OS version. It won't help to make your application shine on Windows 2000 e.g., but you could be ensured that it will have a native look and fill over the next coming Windows version. The Delphi 6 TButton is rendered nicely (with gradient + glowing effect) under Vista/Seven. So IMHO relying on MS Ribbon Framework is smarter than on any other third-party component.

Answer (score 7):

i use the Windows Ribbon Framework - the native component that ships with Windows (7).

Here's a super-short primer on the Windows Ribbon Framework from Delphi; copy-paste of important parts of code, without much explanation:

```
procedure TfrmTicketDetail.ShowScenicRibbon;
begin
    try
        Fframework := UIRibbon.CoUIRibbonFramework.Create;
        Fframework.Initialize(Self.Handle, Self); //Give the ribbon the hwnd, and our implementation of uiapplication for callbacks
        OleCheck(Fframework.LoadUI(hInstance, 'APPLICATION_RIBBON'));
    except
        on e:Exception do
        begin
            if DebugHook > 0 then
                raise;
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

But it starts to get hairy, since you have to follow Microsoft's API.

```
{IUIApplication}
function  OnViewChanged(viewId: SYSUINT; typeID: UI_VIEWTYPE; const view: IUnknown;
      verb: UI_VIEWVERB; uReasonCode: SYSINT): HResult; stdcall;
function  OnCreateUICommand(commandId: SYSUINT; typeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
      out commandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HResult; stdcall;
function  OnDestroyUICommand(commandId: SYSUINT; typeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
      const commandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HResult; stdcall;
```

And then you have to implement them:

```
function TfrmTicketDetail.OnViewChanged(viewId: SYSUINT;
     typeID: UI_VIEWTYPE; const view: IUnknown; verb: UI_VIEWVERB;
     uReasonCode: SYSINT): HResult;
var
    cy: integer;
begin
    Result := S_OK;

    //viewID: The ID for the view. Only a value of zero is valid.
    if viewID <> 0 then
       Exit;

    //typeID: The only declared typeID is UI_VIEWTYPE_RIBBON
    if typeID <> UI_VIEWTYPE_RIBBON then
       Exit;

    case verb of //there are only 4 verbs: create, destroy, size, error
    UI_VIEWVERB_CREATE:
        begin
            {   The view was resized.
                In the case of the Ribbon view, the application should call
                GetHeight() to determine the height of the Ribbon.}
            (view as IUIRibbon).GetHeight(cy);
            bvTopSpacer.Height := cy;
        end;
    UI_VIEWVERB_SIZE:
        begin
            {   The view was resized.
                In the case of the Ribbon view, the application should call
                GetHeight() to determine the height of the Ribbon.}
            (view as IUIRibbon).GetHeight(cy);
            bvTopSpacer.Height := cy;
        end;
    UI_VIEWVERB_DESTROY: {nop};
    UI_VIEWVERB_ERROR: {nop};
    end;

    Result := S_OK;
end;

function TfrmTicketDetail.OnCreateUICommand(commandId: SYSUINT;
  typeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE; out commandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HResult;
begin
    commandHandler := Self; //this form will handle all commands on the ribbon;
    Result := S_OK;
end;

function TfrmTicketDetail.OnDestroyUICommand(commandId: SYSUINT; typeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
      const commandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HResult;
begin
   Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;
```

And then you also have to

- implement `IUICommandHandler`
- author a ribbon XML file
- compile the ribbon XML file with the ribbon compiler
- include the compiled ribbon as a resource:

  `{$RESOURCE '..\Resource\UIRibbon\Ribbon_frmTicketDetails.res'}`

Here's a dump of the ribbon xml i have for my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2009/Ribbon">

    <!-- Commands are like actions, with a name, a numeric ID, caption (LabelTitle), Large and Small images, etc -->
    <Application.Commands>
        <Command Name="cmdNew" Id="0xE100" Symbol="ID_CMD_NEW" LabelTitle="New document" />
        <Command Name="cmdSaveAs" Id="0xE102" Symbol="ID_CMD_SAVEAS" LabelTitle="Save as" />
        <Command Name="cmdOpen" Id="0xE103" Symbol="ID_CMD_OPEN" LabelTitle="Open" />
        <Command Name="cmdExit" Id="0xE104" Symbol="ID_CMD_EXIT" LabelTitle="Exit" />
        <Command Name="cmdUndo" Id="0xE105" Symbol="ID_CMD_UNDO" LabelTitle="Undo" />

        <Command Name="cmdCut" Id="0xE110" Symbol="ID_CMD_CUT" LabelTitle="Cut" />
        <Command Name="cmdCopy" Id="0xE111" Symbol="ID_CMD_COPY" LabelTitle="Copy" />
        <Command Name="cmdPaste" Id="0xE112" Symbol="ID_CMD_PASTE" LabelTitle="Paste" />
        <Command Name="cmdDelete" Id="0xE113" Symbol="ID_CMD_DELETE" LabelTitle="Delete" />
        <Command Name="cmdZoom" Id="0xE114" Symbol="ID_CMD_ZOOM" LabelTitle="Zoom" />

        <Command Name="tabHome" LabelTitle="Home" />

            <Command Name="grpActions" LabelTitle="Actions" />
                <Command Name="cmdSaveAndClose" Id="1101" Symbol="ID_ACTION_SAVEANDCLOSE" LabelTitle="Save and Close">
                    <Command.TooltipTitle>Save and Close (Alt+S)</Command.TooltipTitle>
                    <Command.TooltipDescription>Saves the current ticket and closes the detail screen.</Command.TooltipDescription>
                    <Command.LargeImages>
                        <Image Source="SaveAndClose.bmp" />
                    </Command.LargeImages>
                </Command>
                <Command Name="cmdBack" Id="1102" LabelTitle="Back" />
                <Command Name="cmdControlPanel" Id="1103" LabelTitle="Control Panel" />
                <Command Name="cmdSave" Id="1104" LabelTitle="Save" />

            <Command Name="grpShow" Id="1201" LabelTitle="Show" />
                <Command Name="cmdShowTicket" Id="1202" LabelTitle="Ticket" ></Command>
                <Command Name="cmdShowDiaryEntries" Id="1203" LabelTitle="Diary Entries" >
                    <Command.LargeImages>
                        <Image Source="PencilLog_32x32.bmp" />
                    </Command.LargeImages>
                </Command>
                <Command Name="cmdShowAttachments" Id="1204" LabelTitle="Attachments" />
                <Command Name="cmdShowAuditLog" Id="1205" LabelTitle="Audit Log" />
                <Command Name="cmdShowAdditional" Id="1206" LabelTitle="Additional" />

            <Command Name="grpActivity" LabelTitle="Activity" />
                <Command Name="cmdStartWorking" Id="1301" LabelTitle="Start Working"></Command>
                <Command Name="cmdStopWorking" Id="1302" LabelTitle="Stop Working"></Command>
                <Command Name="cmdPrint" Id="1303" LabelTitle="Print" >
                    <Command.LargeImages>
                        <Image Source="Printer - 256x256.bmp" />
                    </Command.LargeImages>
                    <Command.SmallImages>
                        <Image Source="Printer_16x16.bmp" />
                    </Command.SmallImages>
                </Command>
                <Command Name="cmdDuplicateTicket" Id="1304" LabelTitle="Duplicate Ticket" >
                    <Command.SmallImages>
                        <Image Source="DuplicateTicket16.bmp" />
                    </Command.SmallImages>
                </Command>

            <Command Name="grpTicketStatus" LabelTitle="Ticket Status" />
                <Command Name="cmdCloseTicket" Id="1402" LabelTitle="Close Ticket" />
                <Command Name="cmdOnHold" Id="1403" LabelTitle="On Hold" />
                <Command Name="cmdReadyForInstall" Id="1404" LabelTitle="Ready for install" />
                <Command Name="cmdReopenTicket" Id="1405" LabelTitle="Reopen Ticket" />

    </Application.Commands>

    <!-- Above is all the commands (i.e. Actions). Now we get to the tool on screen (i.e. a DFM) -->
    <Application.Views>
        <Ribbon>

            <!-- Items that appear under the "round button" menu -->
            <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <ApplicationMenu CommandName="cmdFileMenu">
                    <MenuGroup>
                        <Button CommandName="cmdNew" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdOpen" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdSave" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdSaveAs" />
                    </MenuGroup>
                    <MenuGroup>
                        <Button CommandName="cmdExit" />
                    </MenuGroup>
                </ApplicationMenu>
            </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

            <!--What commands to add to the quick access toolbar
                    Right now only Save and Undo, just for fun-->
            <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolbar>
                <QuickAccessToolbar>
                    <QuickAccessToolbar.ApplicationDefaults>
                        <Button CommandName="cmdSave" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdUndo" />
                    </QuickAccessToolbar.ApplicationDefaults>
                </QuickAccessToolbar>
            </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolbar>

            <!-- And now finally the actual tabs -->
            <Ribbon.Tabs>
                <!--Our one and only tab is "Home" -->
                <Tab CommandName="tabHome">
                    <Tab.ScalingPolicy>
                        <ScalingPolicy>
                            <ScalingPolicy.IdealSizes>
                                <Scale Group="grpActions" Size="Medium"/>
                                <Scale Group="grpShow" Size="Medium"/>
                                <Scale Group="grpActivity" Size="Medium"/>
                                <Scale Group="grpTicketStatus" Size="Medium"/>
                            </ScalingPolicy.IdealSizes>
                            <Scale Group="grpActions" Size="Small"/>
                            <Scale Group="grpShow" Size="Small"/>
                            <Scale Group="grpActivity" Size="Small"/>
                            <Scale Group="grpTicketStatus" Size="Small"/>
                        </ScalingPolicy>
                    </Tab.ScalingPolicy>

                    <!-- Home\Actions -->
                    <Group CommandName="grpActions" SizeDefinition="FourButtons">
                        <Button CommandName="cmdSaveAndClose" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdBack" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdControlPanel" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdSave" />
                    </Group>

                    <!-- Home\Show group -->
                    <Group CommandName="grpShow" SizeDefinition="FiveButtons">
                        <ToggleButton CommandName="cmdShowTicket" />
                        <ToggleButton CommandName="cmdShowDiaryEntries" />
                        <ToggleButton CommandName="cmdShowAttachments" />
                        <ToggleButton CommandName="cmdShowAuditLog" />
                        <ToggleButton CommandName="cmdShowAdditional" />
                    </Group>

                    <!-- Home\Activity group, with a custom sizing definition 
                            so i get my "FourButtons-TwoBigTwoSmall" look -->
                    <Group CommandName="grpActivity" >
                        <SizeDefinition>
                            <ControlNameMap>
                                <ControlNameDefinition Name="button1"/>
                                <ControlNameDefinition Name="button2"/>
                                <ControlNameDefinition Name="button3"/>
                                <ControlNameDefinition Name="button4"/>
                            </ControlNameMap>
                            <GroupSizeDefinition Size="Large">
                                <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button1" ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button2" ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                <ColumnBreak ShowSeparator="true"/>
                                <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button3" ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button4" ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                            </GroupSizeDefinition>
                            <GroupSizeDefinition Size="Medium">
                                <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button1" ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button2" ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                <ColumnBreak ShowSeparator="true"/>
                                <Row>
                                    <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button3" ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                </Row>
                                <Row>
                                    <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button4" ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                </Row>
                            </GroupSizeDefinition>
                            <GroupSizeDefinition Size="Small">
                                <Row>
                                    <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button1" ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                    <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button3" ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="false" />
                                </Row>
                                <Row>
                                    <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button2" ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="true" />
                                    <ControlSizeDefinition ControlName="button4" ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="false" />
                                </Row>
                            </GroupSizeDefinition>
                        </SizeDefinition>

                        <Button CommandName="cmdStartWorking" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdStopWorking" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdPrint" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdDuplicateTicket" />
                    </Group>

                    <!-- Home\Ticket Status group -->
                    <Group CommandName="grpTicketStatus" SizeDefinition="FourButtons">
                        <Button CommandName="cmdCloseTicket" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdOnHold" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdReadyForInstall" />
                        <Button CommandName="cmdReopenTicket" />
                    </Group>
                </Tab>
            </Ribbon.Tabs>
            <!-- End of the actual tabs -->

        </Ribbon>
    </Application.Views>
</Application>
```

Comment: Much better to use the Delphi component that wraps it, as suggested by @A.Bouchez

Comment: wow that looks like a lot of effort, but thanks for sharing it was interesting seeing that code.

Comment: +1 for putting Great Information on StackOverflow, even though I agree with David about using the already unit-tested wrapper @ABouchez suggested

Comment: @David, Warren: the linked wrapper doesn't work on all versions of Delphi. Some must resort to calling Windows API directly. Also sample code can help understand the wrapper.