# Executing Commands from the Microsoft Ribbon?

Tags: delphi, ribbon, ribbon-control

I have created my first non Delphi Ribbon using the Microsoft Ribbon Framework thanks to the help and advice provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327845/creating-ribbon-styled-applications).

Following the [guide](http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml) that A.Bouchez posted in that thread I have managed to compile my project and see the Microsoft Ribbon in action.

However, I cannot seem to get the Ribbon to respond to input when a Command is executed.

I always use the TActionManager to manage my Events, so all I need is to link each TAction from the TActionManager into the Ribbon. Following the tutorial linked above, I tried the following to no avail:

```
// actNew is the name of a TAction set in the TActionManager
procedure TfrmMain.actNewExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('execute new event');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.CommandCreated(const Sender: TUIRibbon; const Command: TUICommand);
begin
  inherited;

  case Command.CommandId of
    cmdNew: // cmdNew was defined in the Ribbon Designer
    begin
      // link the ribbon commands to the TActions
      actNew.OnExecute(Command as TUICommandAction); // obviously will not work
    end;
  end;
end;
```

So, how do I assign my TActions to the Ribbon?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like Delphi developers are the only people bothering to use the Windows Ribbon Framework. :)

Comment: @Ian, the reason I chose to use the Microsoft Ribbon Implementation was simple, the Delphi TRibbon does not look or function as good. I have not tried the TMS or DevExpress Components but they also dont appear to look as smooth and complete as the Microsoft one. The Microsoft Ribbon works amazingly well.

Comment: On the other hand the Windows Ribbon Framework ribbon doesn't honor the user's font preferences (e.g. IconTitleFont); nor is there any way to manually define the font. (Note: it does honor fonts if they get **over** 14pt, but anything smaller will not get honored by the ribbon). And while the ribbon doesn't honor the user's color preferences, you *can* specify a theme color for the ribbon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to execute the commands from viewing the samples provided (dont know how I missed them!). The events seem to have to be defined independent of TActions, so I guess that is the way to go.

It is possible though linking the Actions OnExecute handler inside the procedure that is used for calling commands for the Ribbon, example:

```
private
  CommandNew: TUICommandAction;
  procedure CommandNewExecute(const Args: TUICommandActionEventArgs);

  procedure UpdateRibbonControls;
strict protected
  procedure RibbonLoaded; override;
  procedure CommandCreated(const Sender: TUIRibbon; const Command: TUICommand); override;

implementation

procedure TfrmMain.RibbonLoaded;
begin
  inherited;

  Color:= ColorAdjustLuma(Ribbon.BackgroundColor, -25, False);
  UpdateRibbonControls;
end;

// set command states here
procedure TfrmMain.UpdateRibbonControls;
begin
  if Assigned(CommandNew) then
    CommandNew.Enabled:= True;
end;

// assign the commands
procedure TfrmMain.CommandCreated(const Sender: TUIRibbon; const Command: TUICommand);
begin
  inherited;

  case Command.CommandId of
    cmdNew: // command id defined in the ribbon designer
    begin
      CommandNew:= Command as TUICommandAction;
      CommandNew.OnExecute:= NewExecute;
    end;
  end;
end;

// command events
procedure TfrmMain.NewExecute(const Args: TUICommandActionEventArgs);
begin
  actNew.OnExecute(nil); // < this is calling the event code from a TAction      
end;
```

The Samples folder inside the Ribbon Framework will demonstrate this more clearer. The Framework can be found here: http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml